# Move-ADobject - Move user from one forest to another forest?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am able to do this cross domain within a forest, but between two forest it is failing.

So the question in the first place... is it possible to move user between forests using powershell>

When I tried this across forest, I get this error:

```
Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=test4,OU=temp,DC=IDENTITYIQ,DC=LAB" -TargetPath "OU=TestOU,DC=connectivity,DC=lab" -TargetServer ConnDC01W16.connectivity.lab  -Verbose -AuthType Negotiate -Server IIQDC01W16.IDENTITYIQ.LAB

Move-ADObject : The naming context could not be found
At line:1 char:14
+ Move-ADObject <<<<  -Identity "CN=test4,OU=temp,DC=IDENTITYIQ,DC=LAB" -TargetPath "OU=TestOU,DC=connectivity,DC=lab"
-TargetServer ConnDC01W16.connectivity.lab  -Verbose -AuthType Negotiate -Server IIQDC01W16.IDENTITYIQ.LAB
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=test4,OU=temp,DC=IDENTITYIQ,DC=LAB:ADObject) [Move-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The naming context could not be found,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works but only if you have at least a one way forest trust to the target forest.